# Dropping multiple foreign keys of unknown name

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a DB schema generated by Hibernate. Hibernate generates FKs by assigning them a generated name like `FK0123456789ABCDEF`.

As part of the upgrade process of an application installed at a customer's site, I need to drop some FKs created by Hibernate long ago. I cannot be sure that their names remain the same from my local installation and the customer's site. **Worse**, their DBA won't allow me to trickle with their UAT and PROD Dbs with a Management Studio client: they want **one** script to run **both** on UAT and PROD **without any error** (violators will be rolled back).

I know how to indentify these FKs. FKs from tables labeled `TA_xxx` to tables labeled `XTB_xx`.

So I ran the following in local

```
SELECT
    name AS FkName,
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS ReferencingTable,
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTable
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) LIKE 'TA_%'
AND OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) LIKE 'XTB_%'
```

Result:

```
FK2A3B4D9E4EF09A0A  TA_BONDS    XTB_IMPORTS
FK2AC809114EF09A0A  TA_LOANS    XTB_IMPORTS
FKFCE5B2C695243BE8  TA_DEAL_SUBMISSIONS XTB_EXPORTS
FKFCE5B2C64757176B  TA_DEAL_SUBMISSIONS XTB_EXPORTS
FK2A52C11573F2E7FF  TA_DEALS    XTB_ORGANIZATIONS
FK2A52C11595243BE8  TA_DEALS    XTB_EXPORTS
FK2A52C1154757176B  TA_DEALS    XTB_EXPORTS
```

They are 7 both on my installation and on customer's site. I wanted to adapt a script like the following

```
DECLARE @fkConstraint SYSNAME
DECLARE @tbName SYSNAME

SELECT
    @fkConstraint= name,
    @tbName = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) LIKE 'TA_%' AND OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) LIKE 'XTB_%'

DECLARE @DropStmt NVARCHAR(500)

SET @DropStmt = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].'+@tbName+' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @fkConstraint

EXEC (@DropStmt)
GO
```

I think I could repeat the above block 7 times to get rid of all FKs, but I'd ask if there is a more automated way, like "DROP CONSTRAINT ... WHERE IN (SELECT ...)"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

One way is dump the result of below query into a Temp Table and execute resulted rows one by one.

```
CREATE TABLE #foregnkeys
    (
      ROWID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
      SQLStmt VARCHAR(3000)
    )

DECLARE @count INT= 0,
    @SQLStmt VARCHAR(3000)


INSERT  INTO #foregnkeys
        SELECT  'alter table [' + sc.name + '].['
                + OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id, DB_ID('DBNAME'))
                + '] drop constraint [' + fk.name + ']'
        FROM    DBNAME.sys.foreign_keys fk
                INNER JOIN DBNAME.sys.tables tbl ON tbl.[object_id] = fk.parent_object_id
                INNER JOIN DBNAME.sys.schemas sc ON sc.[schema_id] = tbl.[schema_id]
        WHERE   tbl.name LIKE 'TA_%'
                OR tbl.name LIKE 'XTB_%'    --- AND of your query is converted to OR


SELECT  @count = ( SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM #foregnkeys )


WHILE ( @count > 0 )  
    BEGIN


        SELECT  @SQLStmt = ( SELECT SQLStmt
                             FROM   #foregnkeys
                             WHERE  ROWID = @count
                           )

        PRINT ( Cast(@count as varchar)+'_ '+ @SQLStmt )
        EXEC ( @SQLStmt)

        SELECT  @count = @count - 1

    END      



DROP TABLE #foregnkeys
```

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same suggestion as @AA.SC made in the previous answer. Dump all constraint names in a temp table, loop over them and prepare a dynamic sql that will drop them all.

```
DECLARE @fkConstraint SYSNAME;
DECLARE @tbName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @DropStmt NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @cnt int, @i int;

SELECT *
into #FK
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) LIKE 'TA_%' AND OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) LIKE 'XTB_%';

-- add helper column for looping
ALTER TABLE #FK add ID int identity;
select * from #FK;

SELECT @cnt = count(*)
from #FK;

SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= @cnt
BEGIN
    set @DropStmt = NULL;

    SELECT
        @fkConstraint= name,
        @tbName = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
    FROM #FK fk
    WHERE fk.Id = @i;

    SET @DropStmt += 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].'+@tbName+' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @fkConstraint;
    SET @i += 1;
END;

print @DropStmt;
-- EXEC (@DropStmt)
GO
```

PS: Hope the code works as it's done in Notepad :)

Comment: Backup&Restore is for that ;-)